# Setting instance data attributes to None in __init__

Tags: python

In Python 3.7, I frequently find myself writing something like this in `__init__`:

```
    self.foo: Optional[Foo] = None
```

For example:

```
window = Window()
# do some more setup here before going to user
path = get_path_from_user()
window.build(path)

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image: Optional[Image] = None

    def build(self, path):
        self.image = Image(path)
```

I justify this to myself as:

1. Wishing to keep `__init__` light (for maximum reuseabilty) or
2. Being unable to complete the instance when `__init__` executes.

However, I typically don't use the None value for any real *meaning* in the code. In this example, suppose a Window is meaningless without an image. It's just a placeholder until `build` is called so...

**Is this an anti-pattern when doing so for either of the two reasons?**
If so, what is a better way to do it?
(Your opinion is what I'm seeking)

Simply removing the line from `__init__` flags a code inspection warning in PyCharm: "Instance Attribute instantiated outside `__init__`". This seems reasonable to me as it ensures I'm able to look in `__init__` and know I'm always seeing all the data attributes.

Comment: It strongly depends on the context, but in general you need to create an object passing a certain set of parameters, to the optional elements a default value is given and if needed they are included later (as an aggregation). If it is mandatory to provide an object with the same attributes it has then be it so. Now, it is rare to see an object which does not need constructor parameters.

Comment: @MiguelAvila thank you. It's not to avoid passing constructor parameters, I always pass them if possible. It's for 2 cases: either Foo construction would be heavy/slow so I'm thinking it shouldn't be mandatory for derived classes. Or if Foo construction can't take place during __init__ because qux is unknown at that point.

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226). I'm sure there's more to your code too, since this is pretty much just instancing things. Keep in mind Code Review requires [concrete code from a project, in its context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652).

Comment: @Mast Thanks for the pointer. I'll add some more concrete code if you think it will help. I thought this question was too much an opinion-question for StackOverflow and a number of people suggested code review would be a better place. Is there a better place to post general questions about coding patterns? I'm learning Python on my own at home and trying not to develop bad habits.

Comment: Remove `def __init__(self):`, deindent `self.image: Optional[Image] = None` and remove the `self.` from `self.image`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz thanks but that would make it a class attribute. If I created a second window it would have to share the same image.

Comment: @Peilonrayz please clarify. The code I'm writing is seeking to have one image per window instance. I believe your suggested changes would create one image for the window class (accessible as Window.image).

Comment: @Peilonrayz just ran it with your suggested changes plus adding Window. in front of image in build (doesn't run otherwise). First instance window1.image.path returns the value of window2.image.path as suspected. So no, it doesn't work that way in Python, at least not on my computer. ;-) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes I did I indeed. "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" when I attempt to print window1.image.path. Without Window. "image" is just a local variable in the method build() so setting it has no effect. Thank you for trying to help but lets end this discussion here.

Comment: @RobinCarter It's still an instance variable when you do `self.image = ...`... [Like it runs fine online](https://ideone.com/NLGQMN) so you must have changed something your side.

Comment: @Peilonrayz yes you're right. Thank you. I didn't know that instance variables could be annotated directly below "class" (I should have read PEP 526 more carefully). I'm trying to avoid setting Image to None so here's the solution I came up with. https://ideone.com/1GkPZB  I can now refactor my code and it will be more readable. Shame the question is closed or I could have given it to you.

Comment: @Peilonrayz well maybe not according to PEP 526: "As a matter of convenience (and convention), instance variables can be annotated in __init__ or other methods, rather than in the class". However I am a believer in consistency and I like the idea of being able to read off a list of all the data attributes and their types without having to scan code that performs actions too.

Comment: @RobinCarter You are right that was added in rev2 of PEP 526. Wow that's grim.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I've come full circle. I now think it should be in init as Optional[Image] = None. 1) If it's annotated below Class: PyCharm doesn't flag that it's not initialised so the error is at runtime 2) Unintended class variable exposed with potential to change behaviour of the instance variable via it's default 3) None does have a useful meaning: it means it's not properly initialised yet. 4) It's explicit which instance variables have not been initialised in init 5) class and instance variables are clearly delineated 6) compact: annotation and default value on the same line in init

Comment: @RobinCarter I would disagree with putting it in `__init__`, but if it works for you then great!

Comment: @Peilonrayz thanks again for your help and for introducing me to ideone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PEP 526, the initializer isn't needed.  Have you tried:

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image: Optional[Image]    # <== this is just a type hint, no initialization

    def build(self, path):
        self.image = Image(path)
```

I don't use PyCharm, so I don't know if it would still complain.

Comment: I would like to do that, or even just self.image: Image. However, that still raises the warning in PyCharm and apparently also in PyLint according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284857/instance-attribute-attribute-name-defined-outside-init. It's a "weak" warning and it can be turned off. PEP 526 seems concerned with type annotations and I did not see an example of an instance data attribute not being initialised in __init__? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations

Comment: This is not how it's done.

Comment: @RootTwo your solution is very close. According to PEP 526, the solution to my problem seems to be to write self.image: Image directly below class Window: and to remove self.image from ```__init__``` altogether. As here https://ideone.com/1GkPZB

Comment: If you use this pattern a lot, I would consider disabling the check in PyCharm or PyLint and creating a custom checker for your use case.  It could check to make sure all instance vars are initalized in either `__init__()` or `build()` (if there is one).

Comment: I've come full circle. I now think it should be in ```__init__``` as ```Optional[Image] = None```. 1) If it's annotated below Class: PyCharm doesn't flag that it's not initialised so the error is at runtime 2) Unintended class variable exposed which might even change behaviour of the instance variable via it's default 3) None does have a *meaning*: it means it's not properly initialised yet. 4) It's explicit which instance variables have not been initialised in ```__init__``` 5) class and instance variables are clearly delineated 6) compact: annotation and default value on the same line